# Swap quoted word in random position with last word in Python

Tags: python, regex, swap

I have a txt file with lines of text like this, and I want to swap the word in
quotations with the last word that is separated from the sentence with a tab:

### it looks like this:

```
This "is" a person    are
She was not "here"    right
"The" pencil is not sharpened    a
```

### desired output:

```
This "are" a person   is
She was not "right"   here
```

### Some ideas:

##### #1: Use Numpy

1. Seperate all the words by whitespace with numpy-> `['This','"is"','a','person',\t,'are']`

**Problems:**

1. How do I tell python the position of the quoted word
2. How to convert the list back to normal text. Concatenate all?

##### #2: Use Regex

1. Use regex and find the word in `""`

```
with open('readme.txt','r') as x:
    x = x.readlines()
swap = x[-1]
re.findall(\"(\w+)\", swap)
```

**Problems:**

1. I don't know what to read the txt file with regex. most examples I see here will assign the entire sentence to a variable.
   Is it something like this?

```
    with open('readme.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    lines.findall(....)
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Do you need to rewrite the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need *re* for something this trivial.

Assuming you want to rewrite the file:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r+') as txt:
    lines = txt.readlines()
    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        words = line.split()
        for i, word in enumerate(words[:-1]):
            if word[0] == '"' and word[-1] == '"':
                words[i] = f'"{words[-1]}"'
                words[-1] = word[1:-1]
                break
        lines[k] = ' '.join(words[:-1]) + f'\t{words[-1]}'
    txt.seek(0)
    print(*lines, sep='\n', file=txt)
    txt.truncate()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

> regex = r'"[\s\S]*"'

```
import re
file1 = open('test.txt', 'r')
count = 0

while True:

    # Get next line from file
    line = file1.readline()

    # if line is empty
    # end of file is reached
    if not line:
        break
    
    get_tab = line.strip().split('\t')[1]
    regex = r'\"[\s\S]*\"'
    print("original: {} mod ----> {}".format(line.strip(), re.sub(regex, get_tab, line.strip().split('\t')[0])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r'"([^"]*)"(.*\t)(.*)')

with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        print(pat.sub(r'"\3"\2\1', line.rstrip()))
```

Prints:

```
This "are" a person     is
She was not "right"     here
"a" pencil is not sharpened     The
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is also a way to solve it:

Input readme.txt contents:

```
This "is" a person  are
She was not "here"  right
"The" pencil is not sharpened   a
```

Code:

```
import re
changed_text = []
with open('readme.txt') as x:
    for line in x:
        splitted_text = line.strip().split("\t") # ['This "is" a person', 'are'] etc.
        if re.search(r'\".*\"', line.strip()): # If a quote is found
            qouted_text = re.search(r'\"(.*)\"', line.strip()).group(1)
            changed_text.append(splitted_text[0].replace(qouted_text, splitted_text[1])+"\t"+qouted_text)
with open('readme.txt.modified', 'w') as x:
    for line in changed_text:
        print(line)
        x.write(line+"\n")
```

Result (readme.txt.modified):

```
Thare "are" a person    is
She was not "right" here
"a" pencil is not sharpened The
```